# How to use type only emit declaration in TS to declare "update:modelValue" event?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Is there any way to declare the `update:modelValue` event emit or any other kind of emits for v-model in Vue JS Ver. 3.3.4 in Typescript using the type only emit declaration which is exemplified in the Vue JS documentation as follows:

```
// 3.3+: alternative, more succinct syntax
const emit = defineEmits<{
  change: [id: number] // named tuple syntax
  update: [value: string]
}>()
```

Obviously, typing `update:modelValue` as the event name in that syntax just breaks the code.

I can only think of using the other ways to declare the emit events just so you can have an event with an event name that has a `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your emit this way :

```
  // 3.3+: alternative, more succinct syntax
  const emit = defineEmits<{
    'update:modelValue': [value: string];
    change: [id: number]; // named tuple syntax
    update: [value: string];
  }>();
```

In JavaScript, there is three ways to create a property in an object:

cf : [Create objects JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects#using_object_initializers)

To create a property with specials characters, you just need to wrap it with quotes.
Hope it works for you!